# Eek. Logic in view. How to perform exorcism?

Tags: model-view-controller, flask

I am using Flask. I know it is not an MVC framework, but I assume it is still a good idea to keep logic out of views (or what serves as a view). But I have a problem, I have logic in what I think is view but I don't know where else I'd put it.

```
@blueprint.route('/foo')
def foo():
    form = SomeWTForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        some_object = SomeObject()
        form.populate_obj(some_object)
        if some_object.attribute == 1:
            return render_template('/path/to/template/one.html')
        if some_object.attribute == 2:
            return render_template('/path/to/template/two.html')
        if some_object.attribute == 3:
            return render_template('/path/to/template/three.html')
        return render_template('/path/to/template/default.html')
    return render_template('/path/to/template/form.html',
                           form=form)
```

Is this OK? Or am what I calling the "view" really more of a controller (and the template is the view)? If this logic doesn't belong here where else would it go? I don't want to teach `SomeObject` about where to route things -- that just doesn't seem right.

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: You can use a dict to map the templates. e.g. `templates = {1: 'one.html', 2: 'two.html', 3: 'three.html'}`, then use like this: `template = templates.get(some_object.attribute, 'default.html')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions decorated with `@app.route` are usually called "views".  Templates are one way to construct the response that's returned from a view.  The framework provided by Flask and Werkzeug is the controller, which manages handling the request/response cycle.

There is nothing wrong with writing code in views, that's their purpose.